# How to implement Android application indexing and deeplinking?

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I want to impertinent application indexing in one of my application and also deep linking. I have little bit idea of implementing deep linking but I first heard term application indexing. so please any one give description how to implement it on my application.

Comment: for dip linking check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979849/what-is-a-deep-link-in-android/33980816#33980816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Indexing SDK allows our systems to promote Search results from installed apps, and provide enhanced display elements, such as your app icon.App Indexing API powers Search autocompletions for their queries to the Google app, which leads them directly back to your app.

Read and Refer

[App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/introduction?hl=en) and [App Indexing API](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish?hl=en)

Comment: for Application Indexing I can get help from your answers.